# Angular return a directive with different html based on what is passed in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive in html code that looks like this

```
 <lcd-code lcdcode="{{data.code}}"></lcd-code>
```

Then my directive call a service and then it will return data in `content`

```
   // the top part of the directive
   template: '<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="content"></div>', //'<div>blah</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var res = "";
            var promise = customerService.getKey(attrs.lcdcode)
                .then(function (result) {
                    res = result;
                    scope.content = result;

                    console.log('scope.content', scope.content);
                })
                .catch(function () {
                    console.log('problem');
                });

        }
       //bottom part of directive ...
```

What I am passing in as  data.code is  0 or 1 etc..

So what I really want to do is custom build the html that is sent back ..

Say it is a `0` passed in

Then I want to send back out

```
  <div>ok now</div>
```

However if it a `1` then I want to sent back out

```
   <div>
      <div> this is not ok</div>
   </div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your use case as simple as you described? Then you could use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch).

Place a controller behind your module that sets `lcdcode` as soon as `customerService.getKey` returns and your HTML could look like this:

```
<div ng-switch="vm.lcdcode">
  <div ng-switch-when="0">ok now</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="1">This is not ok</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="2">Foo</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>Bar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **ng-bind-html-unsafe has been deprecated**
>   [read here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/813)

To work [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml),
You need to include [angular-sanitize.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.js)

and inject `ngSanitize` in the root module

`angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])`

```
.directive('lcdCode', function() {

    return {
      scope: {
        lcdcode: '<'
      },
      template: '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var value = 1;
        scope.content = "ok now";
        if (scope.lcdcode == 1) {
          scope.content = "this is not ok";

        }

      }
    }
  })
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hdSTu9JezsJwTpsvlZJb?p=preview)